Find the norm of a functional on $l^2$
I came across this problem:
Let $\phi:l^2\to K$ be defined as $\phi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{n}$, find $\lVert\phi\rVert$.
I noticed that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{n}\right|\leq\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}\lVert x\rVert_2$. Then $\lVert\phi\rVert\leq\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$. The idea now is to construct a sequence $\{x^m\}_{m\geq1}$ in $l^2$ such that $lim_{n\to\infty}|\phi(x^m)|=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$. This is where I got stuck. I tried to analyze what happens to sequences of $l^2$ with a finite number of non-zero elements. In particular, if $x=(x_1,0,\dots)$, the best candidate seems to be $x=(1,0,\dots)$. When $x=(x_1,x_2,0,\dots)$ I get that $x=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},0,\dots\right)$ is best, which satisfies $|\phi(x)|\approx1.118$. I wanted to keep adding non_zero terms but it becomes hard to continue with this logic. Maybe the bound is too big. Is this approach correct? I'll appreciate any idea or correction.

What about taking $(x_n)_n=(1/n)_n$ so that in the Cauchy-Schwarz we have equality... ?!

I think that the issue with $(x_n)n=(\frac{1}{n})n$ is that it does not belong to the unit ball of $l^2$. The definition I have for $\lVert\phi\rVert$ is the $sup{x\in B{l^2}}\lVert\phi(x)\rVert$.

OK, then take it divided by its norm.

Ok, now the sequence is in the unit ball of $l^2$, but its norm equals $1$ and I do not arrive at the bound that I want. I mean that $\phi\left(\frac{x}{M}\right)=\frac{1}{M}\phi(x)=1$ where $M=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$ and $x=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)_n$. Is there a result that I'm missing that allows me to conclude that $\lVert\phi\rVert=M$ based on the previous?

@dan_fulea I considered again your initial sequence. I have that $|\phi(x)|\leq\lVert\phi\rVert\lVert x\rVert_2$, then $\lVert\phi\rVert\geq\frac{|\phi(x)|}{\lVert x\rVert_2}$. If $x$ is as given above, then $\lVert\phi\rVert\geq\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$. This together with the initial bound due to Cauchy-Schwarz implies that $\lVert\phi\rVert=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$.
